# Geocoding errors for zipcodes with geocode function using googleway and ggmap package

Tags: ggmap, geocode, googleway

```
library(ggmap)
library(tidyverse)
#create data frame for zipcode
data.new <- c(21022, 20380, 22194, 20414, 20402, 22350, 20451, 56998, 88888,
          20417, 75059, 90210, 11437, 10101, 10275, 10269, 10111, 98490)
data.new <- data.frame(data.new)
data.new <- data.new %>% rename(zipcode=data.new)
data.new$zipcode <- as.character(data.new$zipcode)
register_google(key = "api_key")
data.new_ggmap <- geocode(location = data.new$zipcode, output = "latlona", source = "google")
data.new_ggmap <- cbind(data.new, data.new_ggmap)

#print 
data.new_ggmaps[, 1:18]
```

Do any know how to fix this error? Note: I am working from home on personal pc

OPTION2

```
###OPTION2##############################################################
library(googleway)
library(tidyverse)
google_api_key <- "api_key"

#create data frame for zipcode
data.new <- c(21022, 20380, 22194, 20414, 20402, 22350, 20451, 56998, 88888,
              20417, 75059, 90210, 11437, 10101, 10275, 10269, 10111, 98490)
data.new <- data.frame(data.new)
data.new <- data.new %>% rename(zipcode=data.new)
data.new$zipcode <- as.character(data.new$zipcode)

# initilize some columns to store the google data
data.new$goog_address_components_ <- NA
data.new$goog_formatted_address_ <- NA
data.new$goog_geometry_ <- NA
data.new$goog_place_id_ <- NA
data.new$goog_types_ <- NA
data.new$latitude <- NA
data.new$longitude <- NA

# loop through the rows of the data frame, passing the each zipcode of 
# the trip to the google api each time
for(k in 1:nrow(data.new)){
  
  # print the loop index to see the progress of the loop
  print(k)
  
  # wrap everything in a try catch statement so that if there is an error, it just
  # skips the problem case and keeps going
  tryCatch({ 
    
    # define the search string by  using the zipcode
    search_string <- data.new$zipcode[k]
    
    # pass the search string to the google way geocoding function, you 
    # have to have your own google API key to do this.
    response<- google_geocode(search_string,
                              key = google_api_key)
    
    # get the results from the api response
    results_df <- response$results 
    
    # add the results from the api response to the existing data frame
    data.new$goog_address_components_[k] <- results_df$address_components
    data.new$goog_formatted_address_[k] <- results_df$formatted_address
    data.new$goog_geometry_[k] <- results_df$geometry
    data.new$goog_place_id_[k] <- results_df$place_id
    data.new$goog_types_[k] <- results_df$types
    
    
  }, error = function(e){cat("ERROR :",conditionMessage(e), "\n")})
  
}

#########################################################################
```

I have the following error using googleway pakage

```
[1] 1
[1] 2
ERROR : replacement has 17 rows, data has 18 
[1] 3
ERROR : replacement has 17 rows, data has 18 
[1] 4
ERROR : replacement has 17 rows, data has 18 
[1] 5
ERROR : replacement has 17 rows, data has 18 
[1] 6
ERROR : replacement has 17 rows, data has 18 
[1] 7
ERROR : replacement has 17 rows, data has 18 
[1] 8
ERROR : replacement has 17 rows, data has 18 
[1] 9
ERROR : replacement has 17 rows, data has 18 
[1] 10
ERROR : replacement has 17 rows, data has 18 
[1] 11
ERROR : replacement has 17 rows, data has 18 
[1] 12
ERROR : replacement has 17 rows, data has 18 
[1] 13
ERROR : replacement has 17 rows, data has 18 
[1] 14
ERROR : replacement has 17 rows, data has 18 
[1] 15
ERROR : replacement has 17 rows, data has 18 
[1] 16
ERROR : replacement has 17 rows, data has 18 
[1] 17
ERROR : replacement has 17 rows, data has 18 
[1] 18
ERROR : replacement has 17 rows, data has 18 
Warning message:
In data.new$goog_geometry_[k] <- results_df$geometry :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

I have the following errors from the ggmaps package

Source : https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=21022&key=xxx-L8uKdnfgoejQBIQPFAo6lKAJLbU9E
Source : https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=20380&key=xxx-L8uKdnfgoejQBIQPFAo6lKAJLbU9E
Warning: Geocoding "20380" failed with error:

I try to geocode zipcodes to get lat and lon for each zipcodes

Comment: can you narrow it down to one line of code that's causing the error. Once you find this, solving it will be much easier.

Comment: Thank @ tospig, for responding. When I use ggmap package. The line causing the error is data.new_ggmap <- geocode(location = data.new$zipcode, output = "latlona", source = "google")

Comment: what is the output of `geocode(location = data.new$zipcode, output = "latlona", source = "google")` ?. If this is the line that's causing the issue, you can remove the rest of the code from your question. And also replace `data.new$zipcode` in the function call with the actual value, so we can all see the data you're using